# Exception - System cannot find the file specified

Tags: vb.net, process

I see numerous similar questions to this, but I remain stuck.  I can run nltest.exe from a cmd prompt but not programmatically.

Here is the code that fails with exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll"

```
Dim pz As New Process()
pz.StartInfo.FileName = "nltest.exe"
pz.StartInfo.Arguments = " /dsgetsite > c:\temp\where.txt"
pz.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
pz.Start()
```

So, I modified to use cmd /c as follows:

```
    Dim pz As New Process()
    pz.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    pz.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c nltest /dsgetsite > c:\temp\where.txt"
    '       pz.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
    pz.Start()
    pz.WaitForExit()
```

Using cmd /c, the code runs but only creates an empty file c:\temp\where.txt.
If I run the command manually from the Start menu (Windows 10), this runs fine and the file contains the site location.

Am I making a basic error in either/both of these attempts?

Comment: You need to specify where it is.

Comment: Change the /c in /k and look at the error message

Comment: If the same commandline works when executed at the console but not when invoked via `Process.Start` it is often because the application being executed assumes the location of its working directory. `Process.Start` uses your own app's working directory by default, so an app assuming that it's working directory is the folder containing its own EXE will fail to find files there. Can you set the `WorkingDirectory` of your `ProcessStartInfo` to the path of the folder containing 'nltest.exe'?

Comment: Adding pz.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\Windows\System32"  made no difference

Comment: adding the `/k` leaves cmd window open and shows an error: `'nltest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  Googling that leads me to believe that I need to run this as Administrator perhaps.

Comment: Adding `pz.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"` and `pz.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True` prompts me for elevated cmd and then again complains that the System cannot find the file.  Crap.   This link points to an alternate approach: [http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.dsgetsitename], but I need to study it apparently as the example failed for me.

Comment: I took another approach as referenced in pinvoke [http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.dsgetsitename.  I converted the c# code from [http://adcoding.com/using-dsgetsitename-in-c-sample-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-site-where-a-computer-resides/ and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the active directory function dsgetsite, I gave up on commandline function nltest and translated the c# (using [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com)) found at http://adcoding.com/using-dsgetsitename-in-c-sample-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-site-where-a-computer-resides/ based on netapi32.dll.

I added this line to my IMPORTS section of my vb.net code module

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

I then added to the main Module

```
  <DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
  Public Function DsGetSiteName(ByVal ComputerName As String, <Out> ByRef SiteName As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function

  Public Function GetLocation()
       Dim pSiteInfo As IntPtr
       Dim sSiteName As String = ""
        If DsGetSiteName(String.Empty, pSiteInfo) = 0 Then
              sSiteName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pSiteInfo)
        End If
       Return sSiteName 
  End Function
```

And when I want to find the site name of a workstation from that workstation, I call the function GetLocation().